# Problems with ws2812 module. init() is nil, write() does not work as documented

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying out an Adafruit neopixel array with the ESP8266 and the nodeMCU firmware.

Using following custom build:

> NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
>       branch: master
>       commit: c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883
>       SSL: false
>       modules: bmp085,file,gpio,i2c,net,node,tmr,uart,wifi,ws2812
>   build   built on: 2016-05-24 13:48
>   powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.4.0

When I call `ws2812.init()`, this is what I get in ESPlorer:

```
> ws2812.init();
stdin:1: attempt to call field 'init' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
```

When calling `ws2812.write()`, I get this output:

```
> ws2812.write(string.char(255,0,0,255,0,0));
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'write' (number expected, got string)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'write'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
```

It seems, the module ws2812 is there in any form, but has different signatures, as documented (https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/ws2812/).

Any ideas?
Thanks, Gerd

Comment: Ok, seems that the documentation is out of sync with the firmware builder... executing just the write this way works: `ws2812.write(4, string.char(255, 255, 0))`

Comment: Docs are for the dev branch and you have the master branch firmware.

Comment: Do you need any more feedback? If not please [close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: what is the 4 in the function call?

Comment: worked it out, its the output pin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously built your firmware with http://nodemcu-build.com/ (disclaimer: it's my site). It allows you to select a NodeMCU firmware branch, currently `master` or `dev`.

The documentation link you posted is for the `dev` branch (/en/**dev**/en/modules/...). RTD automatically forwards you to the `dev` branch because our revised documentation is not yet in the master branch. If you care about that progress you might want to follow https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1146.

So, just get a firmware from the `dev` branch and you're all set.